# LI items not showing in the same font size

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I have edited my home page using sharepoint designer to include a un-ordered list to display a series of links. For some reason the very first link "Provost and Vice President for Academic Affairs" appears smaller than the rest of the link Li items.

I've checked to make sure the font sizes are the same. both looking at the source code in Sharepoint Designer and Chrome Developer Tools confirms this. However Chrome shows the computed style as only being 11pt.

```
                    <ul>
                        <li style="width: 916px">
                        <a href="Provost%20and%20Vice%20President%20for%20Academic%20Affairs/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        <span style="font-size: large">Provost and Vice President for Academic Affairs</span></a><ul>
                            <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                            <a href="College%20of%20Business%20Administration/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                            College of Business Administration</a></li>
                            <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                            <a href="College%20of%20Education/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                            College of Education</a></li>
                            <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                            <a href="Allen%20E%20Paulson%20College%20of%20Engineering%20and%20Informa/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                            Allen E. Paulson College of Engineering and 
                            Information Technology</a></li>
                            <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                            <a href="Jack%20N%20Averitt%20College%20of%20Graduate%20Studies/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                            Jack N. Averitt College of Graduate Studies</a></li>
                            <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                            <a href="College%20of%20Health%20and%20Human%20Sciences/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                            College of Health and Human Sciences</a></li>
                            <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                            <a href="College%20of%20Liberal%20Arts%20and%20Social%20Sciences/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                            College of Liberal Arts and Social Sciences</a></li>
                            <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                            <a href="JiannPing%20Hsu%20College%20of%20Publich%20Health/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                            Jiann-Ping Hsu College of Public Health</a></li>
                            <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                            <a href="College%20of%20Science%20and%20Mathematics/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                            College of Science and Mathematics</a></li>
                            <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                            <a href="Zach%20Henderson%20Library/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                            Zach Henderson Library</a></li>
                            <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                            <a href="Associate%20Provost/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                            Associate Provost</a></li>
                            <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                            <a href="Associate%20Vice%20President%20for%20Continuing%20Education/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                            Associate Vice President for Continuing 
                            Education</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                        <a href="Vice%20President%20for%20Business%20and%20Finance/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        Vice President for Business and Finance</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                        <a href="Vice%20President%20for%20Business%20and%20Finance/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        Vice President for Government Relations and 
                        Community Engagement</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                        <a href="Vice%20President%20for%20Information%20Technology%20and%20Chie/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        Vice President for Information Technology and Chief 
                        Information Officer</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                        <a href="Vice%20President%20for%20Research%20and%20Economic%20Developme/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        Vice President for Research and Economic Development</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                        <a href="Vice%20President%20for%20Student%20Affairs%20and%20Enrollment/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        Vice President for Student Affairs and Enrollment 
                        Management</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                        <a href="Vice%20President%20for%20University%20Advancement%20and%20Pres/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        Vice President for University Advancement and 
                        President of Georgia Southern Foundation</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know if this is a typo or im missing somthing but your missing what everything else has! `il;` as its at the top and is only within the `ul` , i guess easily missed?

currently looks like:

```
                <ul>
                    <li style="width: 916px">
                    <a href="Provost%20and%20Vice%20President%20for%20Academic%20Affairs/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                    <span style="font-size: large">Provost and Vice President for Academic Affairs</span></a><ul>
```

shouldnt it be?

```
                <ul>
                    <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                    <a href="Provost%20and%20Vice%20President%20for%20Academic%20Affairs/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                    <span style="font-size: large">Provost and Vice President for Academic Affairs</span></a></li><ul>
```

spot the difference? how did i notice it? i use notepad++ ;) good tool and life saver! your not closing `<li` so it had a little fit ;)

full working code:

```
                <ul>
                    <li style="width: 916px">
                    <a href="Provost%20and%20Vice%20President%20for%20Academic%20Affairs/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                    <span style="font-size: large">Provost and Vice President for Academic Affairs</span></a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                        <a href="College%20of%20Business%20Administration/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        College of Business Administration</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                        <a href="College%20of%20Education/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        College of Education</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                        <a href="Allen%20E%20Paulson%20College%20of%20Engineering%20and%20Informa/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        Allen E. Paulson College of Engineering and 
                        Information Technology</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                        <a href="Jack%20N%20Averitt%20College%20of%20Graduate%20Studies/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        Jack N. Averitt College of Graduate Studies</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                        <a href="College%20of%20Health%20and%20Human%20Sciences/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        College of Health and Human Sciences</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                        <a href="College%20of%20Liberal%20Arts%20and%20Social%20Sciences/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        College of Liberal Arts and Social Sciences</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                        <a href="JiannPing%20Hsu%20College%20of%20Publich%20Health/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        Jiann-Ping Hsu College of Public Health</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                        <a href="College%20of%20Science%20and%20Mathematics/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        College of Science and Mathematics</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                        <a href="Zach%20Henderson%20Library/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        Zach Henderson Library</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                        <a href="Associate%20Provost/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        Associate Provost</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                        <a href="Associate%20Vice%20President%20for%20Continuing%20Education/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                        Associate Vice President for Continuing 
                        Education</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                    <a href="Vice%20President%20for%20Business%20and%20Finance/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                    Vice President for Business and Finance</a></li>
                    <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                    <a href="Vice%20President%20for%20Business%20and%20Finance/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                    Vice President for Government Relations and 
                    Community Engagement</a></li>
                    <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                    <a href="Vice%20President%20for%20Information%20Technology%20and%20Chie/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                    Vice President for Information Technology and Chief 
                    Information Officer</a></li>
                    <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                    <a href="Vice%20President%20for%20Research%20and%20Economic%20Developme/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                    Vice President for Research and Economic Development</a></li>
                    <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                    <a href="Vice%20President%20for%20Student%20Affairs%20and%20Enrollment/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                    Vice President for Student Affairs and Enrollment 
                    Management</a></li>
                    <li style="width: 916px; font-size: large;">
                    <a href="Vice%20President%20for%20University%20Advancement%20and%20Pres/Forms/Upload.aspx">
                    Vice President for University Advancement and 
                    President of Georgia Southern Foundation</a></li>
                </ul>
```